# "conda init" for conda 4.6 not working on macOS mojave

Tags: anaconda, conda

The conda 4.6 releaser announcement says to run

```
conda update conda
```

and then

```
conda init
```

The update works fine, but the init gives an error:

```
$ conda init
no change     /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xonsh/conda.xsh
no change     /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
needs sudo    /Users/xxxxxx/.bash_profile
No action taken.
Operation failed.
```

I don't have a .bash_profile. I do have a /Users/xxxxxx/.profile, but it's not directly executable with or without sudo.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure there's no `.bash_profile` file? What is the output of `ls -la /Users/xxxxx`?

Comment: ls -la /Users/xxxxxx returns a lot of output. There is a .bash_history and .bash_sessions, but no .bash_profile. There is a .profile which is where my session startup stuff goes. I've had things set up this way since fairly early versions of macOS with no problems (until, possibly, now).

Comment: What if you do `touch ~/.bash_profile` and then try `conda init` again?

Comment: Identical to a bug filed at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8244

Answer (score 6):

I too face similar issue, however after sourcing the conda.sh file, the problem is resolved. You can have a check.

```
source /Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```